# Which sentence is correct (off of)?

Tags: sentence-construction

1.

> He cut the pie and chomped a substantial piece of it

2.

> He cut the pie and chomped a substantial piece off it

3.

> He cut the pie and chomped a substantial piece off of it

In my understanding, [2] is wrong, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[chomp](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chomp)** means to chew noisily.

Sentence 1 means that he cut a piece of pie and then chewed it noisily.

2 and 3 don't work, because **off** and **off of** relate to separating one piece from the rest. Chewing noisily is not a plausible way of separating a piece from a pie.

If you remove the chomping bit, then 2 and 3 make more sense, because **cut off** is a widely used compound verb.

> 2a. He cut a substantial piece off it
>
> 3a. He cut a substantial piece off of it

3a is not really correct, but you will hear it in informal spoken English. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piece%20off%20it%2Cpiece%20off%20of%20it%3A%20eng_gb_2012%2C%20piece%20off%20of%20it%3A%20eng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpiece%20off%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiece%20off%20of%20it%3A%20eng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that it does occasionally occur in writing too, though exclusively in American English.